# Region and DiracDelta

Tags: numerical-integration, regions

The following integral evaluates as expected to 1:

```
Integrate[ DiracDelta[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -Sqrt[1 - x^2], Sqrt[1 - x^2]}]
```

However, if we use a Region, the integral is no more evaluated:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[]]
```

Is there a reason behind or is this a bug?

Comment: The integral under consideration makes no sense: so-called $\delta$-function is not a usual function, but a distribution (see e.g. https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Generalized_function).

Comment: @user64494 your comment is not only wrong, but is particularly unhelpful in solving the integral in question.

Comment: BTW, the inner integration `Integrate[DiracDelta[x, y], {y, -Sqrt[1 - x^2], Sqrt[1 - x^2]}]` results in  $$\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\delta (x) \left(2 \theta \left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)-1\right),(\Im(x)=0\land -1\leq \Re(x)\leq 1)\lor \Re(x)=0\right] $$. I wonder  $\Re(x)=0$.

Comment: The problem is not only with DiracDelta, but if you use the same forms for `Sin[x y]` you get the same behavior.  It can do one, but not the other.

Comment: @Bill Watts: Sorry, don't understand you: even in the Mathematica's implementation `DiracDelta[x]` makes no sense for complex values of `x`. `Integrate[Sin[x*y], {y, -Sqrt[1 - x^2], Sqrt[1 - x^2]}]` performs `0` in version 12.0.

Comment: @Bill Watts: I got your point. I don't find the result of `Integrate[Sin[x*y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[]]` as a bug. It is not so simple to write down the bounds of the integrations automatically. `Integrate[
 Sin[x*y], {x, y} \[Element] ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}]]` perfrms `0` and `Integrate[
 DiracDelta[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] 
  ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}]]` produces `1`. However, the latter simply makes no sense.

Comment: @Daniel Huber: If you mean something like to `Integrate[ DiracDelta[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -Sqrt[1 - x^2], Sqrt[1 - x^2]}]==Integrate[Limit[C[n]*Exp[-(x^2+y^2)/n],n->Infinity], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -Sqrt[1 - x^2], Sqrt[1 - x^2]}]`, then it should be noticed  that limit is not a usual limit, but the limit in the weak *topology (see https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Generalized_function again ).

Comment: From here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html .A workaround: if `DiracDelta[x, y] == 
 Limit[e^2/(\[Pi]^2 (e^2 + x^2) (e^2 + y^2)), e -> 0]` then:`Limit[Integrate[(1/Pi*e/(x^2 + e^2))*(1/Pi*e/(y^2 + e^2)), {x, 
     y} \[Element] Disk[], Assumptions -> e >= 0][[1]], e -> 0]`

Comment: Unevaluated is not a bug.  It just means that Mathematica can't do it.  The value of the integral is 1 by the definition of the DiracDelta since the limits of the integral include the origin.  My point in using Sin[x y] was to show that Mathematica's failure to integrate over a region was not limited to DiracDelta.

Comment: Hi Bill, you are right. I think Wolfram needs to do more work on "Region"

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your definition of "reason". :)

Distributions don't obey several important rules of integration of measurable functions.  For example (and probably most importantly), the integral of a distribution over a region of measure zero is not necessarily zero.  Therefore, we have to detect early on the presence of distributions and process those integrals with special code.  Presumably that code, which predates the addition of regions, doesn't know how to deal with region integrals.

You should contact support with your example and request the integrals of distributions over regions be better supported.  I just can't promise how quickly we might be able to add that support.  Integral is a very old and very important function.  Changes to it are not made lightly.

**Clarification:** As noted in the comments, the integral of a distribution over a lower-dimensional is not well defined.  It's potentially ambiguous even if the singular support intersects the boundary of the region of integration.  For example:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]
(*1 - HeavisideTheta[0]*)
```

Some would expect this to be 1/2, but it's really matter of "how you approach 0", so you can defined HeavsideTheta[0] to be whatever you want.  But we don't necessarily get this fancy in higher dimensions:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[x,y], {x,- 1, \[Infinity]}, {y, -1, \[Infinity]}]
(* 0 *)
```

This is a defensible answer, even if it's not the 1/4 that many might expect.  Which may be another reason why we haven't done region integrals and distributions.  For example, how you compute, much less present, the integral of a delta function that lives on the boundary and not the interior of a disk/sphere?

Comment: Itai Seggev (Unfortunately, @ does not work.), Can you kindly give a reliable reference to the definition of " the integral of a distribution over a region"? Neither Encyclopedia of Mathematics nor W. Rudin , Functional Analysis defines that notion. TIA.

Comment: @user64494 I don't have my copy of Rudin handy, but I'm pretty sure he defines the integral of a distribution over an open set contains the support of distribution.  This would be what is meant by "the integral of a distribution over a region".  I will update my answer to clarify that.

Comment: Itai Seggev, Sorry, I prefer arguments over ungrounded words.

Comment: What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: Itai Seggev, despite your claim "but I'm pretty sure he defines the integral of a distribution over an open set contains the support of distribution", I don't find any definition of the definite integral of a distribution over  a set in the Rudin's book.

Comment: So Rudin's not as explicit as some other sources (e.g, Reed & Simon) but he defines measures as distributions in 6.11.  He then proves locality & defines support in 6.19--6.24.  Ergo, a distribution on R^n can be restricted to an open subset of R^n (a region) as long as it contains the support of the distribution.  Now, Mathematica's DircaDelta[x] would be in Rudin's terminology the Dirac measure, with the Dirac distirbution itself being the integral wrt said measure.  But it's perfectly common and well understood to say "integrating the distribution", even if the phrase is technically wrong.

Comment: Itai Seggev, If the $\delta$-distribution is treated as the distribution associated with the atomary measure concentrated at the origin (see "As the measure" section in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function ), then the relation $\int_\mathbb{R} \,d\delta(x)=1$, not the relation $\int_{\mathbb{R} }\delta(x)\,dx=1$, holds. In this case there is a problem with the interpretation of the ODE $y''(x)-y(x)=\delta(x)$ as well as other problems raise.